# CSS center background image horizontally AND THEN repeat vertically?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have a small challenge that I was hoping you could help me out with. I am trying to center a very wide image (2500x20) on the background and have it tile (repeat) down... I can find lots of info on how to center both ways... or how to repeat both ways... but nothing on how to mix the two. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
background: url(http://placehold.it/2500x20) repeat-y center;
```

Demo: http://cssdesk.com/CatAa

Comment: Perfect and simple... just that way I like them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
.foo {
    background-position: 50% 0; /* centers the image horizontally */
    background-repeat: repeat-y; /* tiles it vertically */
}
```